# Duda sobrecarga de operadores

Tags: c++

Tengo dudas respecto al código de a continuación:

```
Complejo Complejo::operator+ (const Complejo &c){
      Complejo resultado;
      resultado.real = real + c.real;
      resultado.img = img + c.img;
      return resultado;
}
```

En este operador, ¿qué diferencia hay entre "real" y "c.real"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el siguiente código estas implementando la suma del elemento actual con otro Complejo y retorna la suma en otro elemento, es decir:

```
Complejo foo = ....;
Complejo foo_2 = ...;
Complejo res = foo + foo_2;
```

Asi que la tarea se realiza usando `foo`, por lo que para acceder a los elementos de foo dentro de la clase podrias usar `this->algun_valor` o simplemente `algun_valor`, pues justmente eso diferencia a `real` y `c.real`, `real` se refiere a `foo` y `c.real` se refiere a `foo_2`